# Conditional probability calculation given correlation

Tags: probability, correlation

I'm struggling with this question:
You are given 2 random standard normal variables with correlation = 0,2
What is the probability that both are negative?

The answer is 0,29 but I have no idea how to get it, except for high-level estimate 0,5*0,5=0,25 and (taking positive correlation) suppose that it is higher then 0,25

Comment: This is not a conditional probability: it's a *bivariate* probability.  The duplicates explain how to find it.